# PowerMock private void method with arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm looking for a unit test for Controllers using Mockito and PowerMock. Every controller has only private void methods with a single argument and a @Autowired service dependency:

```
    public class ProjectController {

    private ProjectServiceImpl service;
    @Autowired
    public void setInjectedBean(ProjectServiceImpl service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    private void createProject(String someString) {
        // do stuff by calling service.doSomething(someString)
    }
}
```

ProjectServiceImpl is annotated with @Service and has only a public void method with a String as argument. As it is too simple, I didn't bother providing the code.
My last attempt to accomplish that test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@PrepareForTest({ProjectController.class, ProjectServiceImpl.class})
class ProjectControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ProjectController controller;
    @Mock
    private ProjectServiceImplservice;
    
    @Test
    void createProject() throws Exception {
        controller = PowerMockito.spy(new ProjectController());

        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(controller, "createProject", new String(""));
    }
}
```

Question 1: is it possible to make PowerMock work aside of Mockito?

Question 2: using PowerMock, what's the most appropriate way of calling for a private void method with argument?

IMPORTANT: Before marking this post as a duplicate, I personally challenge you finding any content how to do so. It seems like there is just no content showing not only how to make both work together, but make PowerMockito calls for a private void method with one or more arguments.

dependencies used for PowerMock:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How does that private method get called normally?

Comment: It is activated by user interaction. Originally, it is annotated with @FXML, which is a javafx annotation. Every time the user clicks on a specific UI component, this routine is automatically activated. For the sake of ease of reproducibility, I adapted the code by removing the original argument (which is MouseEvent) and FXML annotation.

Comment: I'd consider making it protected for ease of testing.

Comment: Makes sense in a test perspective, but this is more like a workaround than a fix as nothing extends my controllers, actually that's precisely what I'm trying to avoid (even though it seems to be the most viable alternative)

Comment: Having all methods private and rely on reflection shenanigans from FXML is a pretty bad code design and nothing you should work around to keep that.

Comment: good point, but I prefer not to keep unnecessary public accessors because it's easier to deal with. Also, the project has a considerable amount of classes (over 200), and for that it's almost a requisite to block the usage of controllers, which I find a better code architecture. In addition, yes, PowerMockito is basically reflection, but its power doesn't come only from it. That's why spying objects exists in test frameworks I guess, it's such a convenient tool that makes reflection much easier to deal with

Comment: may be I read it too fast, but why not provide a Mock for `ProjectServiceImpl` and mock _it_, instead of trying to mock the private method?

Comment: @Eugene good catch, it's for test coverage measurements (SonarCloud), I just have to verify that the service was actually called (since it is the only thing controllers do)